How to apply dhtmlx library in codepen?
i'm trying to test grid in codepen. I'm newbie with codepen and html, javascript. :(
1)This is dhtmlx official example code in docs.
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/9txizaow?text=grid&mode=wide

2)There's HTML, Javascript so i paste it to my codepen
https://codepen.io/youhost/pen/BaXYpZK

but i can't see anything in my codepen. Is there anything wrong in my trying??
Thanks for reading.

Could you please, clarify what do you mean by "anything"?
Grid is displaying in your provided link, while the Pagination is not displaying, as it is available in PRO version only, while you are using non-PRO version from CDN (also, it is v6.0, while the Pagination widget has beed added in v7.0)
